# Does google document AI support thai language?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

For a thai language document, I am trying to extract the text and key-value pairs using Google Document AI. On seeing the result, I can see that the thai language is not retained. Is there any parameter that needs to be passed for thai characters to be recognised as I can get the output only in english characters.

Below link shows that document-ai can support thai language as well.
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Supported Language Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/languages#document_ocr_processor_language_support) specifically refers to languages supported by Optical Character Recognition.

Specific processors may support limited languages. Since you said you're using "key-value pairs", it sounds like you're using the [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) which says on the Processor page that it supports Latin Script languages only. (Which does not include Thai)

[image]

<strike>The documentation could be more clear about language support for individual processors, there is currently work being done to address this.</strike>

**Update 1:** The [Supported Languages Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/languages) has been updated to make this more explicit.

The [Processor List](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list) page also shows language support for each processor type.

**Update 2:** The newest version of the Form Parser processor `pretrained-form-parser-v2.0-2022-11-10` adds support for all 200+ languages supported by the [Document OCR](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_doc-ocr) processor, which should include the Thai language.

Refer to [Managing processor versions](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/manage-processor-versions) for info on how to use this.